# Darken Background - Without affecting elements itself. (Overlay?)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, overlay

I want to darken my background. Normally, its as simple as putting an overlay with a lower z-index than the most front element like seen here:

[image]
<sub>(source: [jankoatwarpspeed.com](http://www.jankoatwarpspeed.com/wp-content/uploads/2009/5/sample.jpg))</sub>

What I want to achieve now is to make the elements behind the overlay STILL be clickable, selectable and so on.

In this example, the links should be clickable, and the text above should be selectable, but STILL be this dark.

I guess I cant archive this with pure CSS, what would be your solution?

Thanks

Comment: background: rgba(0,0,0, 0.3);

Comment: Cant you just use css to change the background colour?

Comment: Why use overlay for that?That can be easily done by changing background color.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/Qq5tQ/232/

Comment: yes, but I need to keep the links and text and everything else darker too. I cant just change the background because then the links will be still the same color. (or in my case the other elements)

Comment: Have a light stylesheet and dark stylesheet, then assign a click function using jQuery to switch between the two.

Comment: @PlicPl Oh I understand what you mean now, you want to darken everything but the video.

Comment: Not suitable for all browsers, but could be helpful: #overlay {
  pointer-events: none;
}

Comment: maybe add an overlay sibling to the video element, then add a show class when lights are turned off

Comment: Well, I found a way like here: http://jsfiddle.net/S4rsh/ But the problem is, that every element is darker now. But I dont want the video to be dark.

Comment: I am making a fiddle.I will post it in 5 mins

Comment: You might want to look at the answers to [How can I make everything outside of a div darker?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/41902801/215552)

Answer (score 0):

Just disable pointer events on your overlay:

```
pointer-events: none;
```

Example:

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/ebcdz

Comment: Does disabling pointer events cause the elements behind the overlay to be clickable? Because that's what the OP is asking for...

Comment: Yes, it basically causes the overlay to passthrough the event, as you can see in the codepen example

Comment: Well, I (and I'm sure others) are blocked from CodePen at work. That's one of the reasons Stack Overflow came up with [Stack Snippets](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/358992/215552), which work within the domains owned by Stack Overflow... But I just noticed that this is a really old question and answer, so never mind :).

Answer (score 0):

See this fiddle.My technique is to add the same elements to the overlay div and to set the color of text of the href text to the background color of overlay so that it appears invisible.See this fiddle.

http://jsfiddle.net/5Ux5t/1/

CSS for href within overlay div to make it invisible

```
#overlay a{
    color:black;
}
```

Actually there are links in the overlay too.I just added the above CSS to make them invisible.See this:

http://jsfiddle.net/5Ux5t/