# How can I make everything outside of a div darker?

Tags: html, css, layout

I've got a cart drawer that opens from the right on click. I'd like for everything outside of it to become darker when it is opened such that only the div (cart drawer) is focused. Any tips on how I can do this?

Comment: any html and css to show a basic example of what you tried so far ?

Comment: Your snippet doesn't help much, a piece of your HTML would have been  efficient instead the script.

Comment: Sorry, i meant :`{% if cart.item_count > 0 %}` for instance is not helpfull, a plain HTML sample would have been enough to show your structure and which element is suppose to be light ...

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Basicly, a hudge `shadow` might do :*(click any numbered divs to darken what's around it)*

**Edit** from your comment, i would propose: `.cart-container{box-shadow:0 0 0 2000px rgba(0,0,0,0.5);}` demo below for effect it can have.

```css
div:focus {
  position:relative;/* bring on top;*/
  box-shadow:0 0 0 1600px rgba(0,0,0,0.65);/* dark around it */
}

/* demo purpose*/
body {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  counter-reset: divs -1;
  margin:0;
}
div {
  counter-increment: divs;
  height: 120px;
  width: 120px;
  background: turquoise;
}
div:nth-child(odd) {
  background: tomato;
}
div:not(:first-of-type):before {
  content: counter(divs);
  display: block;
  font-size: 2em;
  margin: 1em;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<div>tabindex for demo catches click, but not me. <b>switch light back on</b></div>
<div tabindex="0"></div>
<div tabindex="0"></div>
<div tabindex="0"></div>
<div tabindex="0"></div>
<div tabindex="0"></div>
<div tabindex="0"></div>
<div tabindex="0"></div>
<div tabindex="0"></div>
<div tabindex="0"></div>
<div tabindex="0"></div>
<div tabindex="0"></div>
<div tabindex="0"></div>
<div tabindex="0"></div>
<div tabindex="0"></div>
<div tabindex="0"></div>
<div tabindex="0"></div>
<div tabindex="0"></div>
<div tabindex="0"></div>
<div tabindex="0"></div>
<div tabindex="0"></div>
<div tabindex="0"></div>
<div tabindex="0"></div>
<div tabindex="0"></div>
```

a mask in fixed position can also be used to catch any click outside it:

```css
div.toShowTop {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1;
  /* bring on top;*/
  box-shadow: 0 0 0 1600px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.65);
  /* dark around it */
}
div.toShowTop ~.mask {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  left: 50px;/* to see effect */
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
}
body div.toShowTop {
  background: yellow;
  order: 1;
}
div:nth-child(8)~div {
  order: 2
}
/* demo purpose*/

body {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  counter-reset: divs -1;
  margin: 0;
}
div {
  counter-increment: divs;
  height: 120px;
  width: 120px;
  background: turquoise;
  cursor: pointer;
}
div:nth-child(odd) {
  background: tomato;
}
div:not(:first-of-type):before {
  content: counter(divs);
  display: block;
  font-size: 2em;
  margin: 1em;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<div tabindex="0" class="toShowTop">div to show</div>
<div tabindex="0"></div>
<div tabindex="0"></div>
<div tabindex="0"></div>
<div tabindex="0"></div>
<div tabindex="0"></div>
<div tabindex="0"></div>
<div tabindex="0"></div>
<div tabindex="0"></div>
<div tabindex="0"></div>
<div tabindex="0"></div>
<div tabindex="0"></div>
<div tabindex="0"></div>
<div tabindex="0"></div>
<div tabindex="0"></div>
<div tabindex="0"></div>
<b class="mask"></b>
<!-- can be generated via js -->
```

You may also use a pseudo from another element to avoid extra markup:

```css
div.toShowTop {
  position:relative;
  z-index:1;/* bring on top;*/
}
div.toShowTop  + div:after {
  content:'';
  position:fixed;
  top:0;
  bottom:0;
  right:0;
  left:50px;
  background:rgba(0,0,0,0.75);
  cursor:auto;
}
body div.toShowTop {
  background:yellow;
  order:1;}
div:nth-child(8)~div {order:2}
/* demo purpose*/
body {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  counter-reset: divs -1;
  margin:0;
}
div {
  counter-increment: divs;
  height: 120px;
  width: 120px;
  background: turquoise;
  cursor:pointer;
  
}
div:nth-child(odd) {
  background: tomato;
}
div:not(:first-of-type):before {
  content: counter(divs);
  display: block;
  font-size: 2em;
  margin: 1em;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<div tabindex="0" class="toShowTop"> div to show </div>
<div tabindex="0"></div>
<div tabindex="0"></div>
<div tabindex="0"></div>
<div tabindex="0"></div>
<div tabindex="0"></div>
<div tabindex="0"></div>
<div tabindex="0"></div>
<div tabindex="0"></div>
<div tabindex="0"></div>
<div tabindex="0"></div>
<div tabindex="0"></div>
<div tabindex="0"></div>
<div tabindex="0"></div>
<div tabindex="0"></div>
<div tabindex="0"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with a pseudo element...

```css
div {
  background: #fff;
}

div:after {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0; bottom: 0; right: 0; left: 0;
  background: rgba(0,0,0,0.8);
  content: '';
  z-index: -1;
}
```

```html
<div>div</div>
```

But a better solution might be to create a separate element that serves as the background/mask. This will give you more control over the layout.

```css
section {
  background: white;
}

.mask {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0; bottom: 0; right: 0; left: 0;
  background: rgba(0,0,0,0.8);
  z-index: 1;
}

.show {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 2;
}
```

```html
<section>section</section>

<section class="show">show this</section>

<section>section</section>

<div class="mask"></div>
```